# FBX Model not displaying correctly in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0, game-engine

Recently I have posted the same question that my FBX model was not showing correctly in XNA. I got a answer to the question and the model was displayed slightly better, but it is still not displaying correctly.

What it should look like is this:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B54ow8GRluDUYTBubTQ4bjBramM
But it shows as:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B54ow8GRluDUNXR5bmJUMVJFTUk

My drawing code is:

```
public void Draw(Matrix projection, Matrix view)
{
   Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
   model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

   foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
   {
      foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
      {
         effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
         effect.View = view;
         effect.Projection = projection;
         effect.World = Matrix.CreateRotationX(-270) *
                        transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                        Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
      }
   mesh.Draw();
   }
}
```

Can someone please help!
Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a google doc account, I cannot see your link. Use Imgur next time.

Comment: You dont need an google account

Comment: Well, when I click the link, it asks me to login.

Comment: gO HERE: http://www.flickr.com/photos/89965250@N02/

Comment: Hmm... My first guess would be that the normal of your triangles are flipped, making them rendered inside out. But without being able to move around and see, but hard to say for sure.

Comment: Could you try setting `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullClockwise`? Also, if you're using 2D sprites somewhere, maybe you could also set `GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DepthBufferEnable = true;`.

Comment: The RasterizerState has improved it a bit more, but it is still not perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{

   GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

   #region ResetGraphic

   ResetGraphic();

   #endregion
   #region render 3D
   BeginRender3D();
   //Render 3D here
   #endregion
   #region render 2D

   //Render 2D here
   #endregion

}

public void ResetGraphic()
{              
   GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
   GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.None;
   GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
   GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.AnisotropicWrap;

}

public void BeginRender3D()
{
   GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
   GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
}
```

Comment: also depending on your art you may need to add this 
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;

Comment: Thanks, sorry i took so long to get back

Answer (score 3):

Based on your previous question where the Xna rendered image showed that you were rendering 2d and 3d items, it is important to reset some graphics states between 2d & 3d.

Specifically, after rendering the 2d stuff, add these lines:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

These settings are necessary for 3d but they get changed when calling SpriteBatch.Begin() so it is necessary to change them back before the 3d stuff.

Here is the blog post explaining it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx